# JavaFx columnspan for textarea in code

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a simple GridPane with 2 columns and 9 rows. I add a TextArea in the 6th row. How can i give this TextArea a Columnspan of 2?

```
        MyFxTextArea textArea = new MyFxTextArea();
        textArea.setMaxHeight(200);
        textArea.setMaxWidth(600);

        page.add(textArea,0,6);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the column span when you are adding the text area to the page:

```
page.add(textArea,0,6,2,1);
```